# Transposing a DataFrame and adding a date index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run some scientific analysis using the new Morningstar Jupyter Notebook. My goal is to build a co-variance table of 17 different benchmarks. The problem I am having is that the data is cross-tabulated. The dates are entered as headers and the returns are indexed to the first row. I am trying to figure out how I can have a date index on the left and all 17 of my indexes across the top. I have tried transposing and removing columns. I have tried extracting rows. I am just learning Python

**The problem:**

[image]

Comment: please post your data, not an image. print df.to_dict(), for example and paste into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to transpose your data.
You can try something like

```
df_transposed = df.transpose()
df_transposed
```

This should set the columns of your first df to be the index of the new one.
(Name will be the first row in the table)
You can then set the column names to the first row of names if you want to refer to each column by the value of the Name.
Something like this should work.

```
df_transposed.columns = df_transposed.loc['Name'].tolist()
```